# How to limit jquery datatable export by 1000 rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How to limit jquery datatable export by first 1000 rows. if data table contains more than 1000 rows and on clicking export button shall show an error message.

```
buttons: [
    {
         extend: 'excelHtml5',
         text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> ' + 'haiexcel',
         title: pageTitle,
         exportOptions: {
            orthogonal: 'export',
            columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
         },
         className: 'btn bg-color-yellow margin-right-5',
         customize: function (xlsx) {
         var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet.xml'];
         $('row:first c', sheet).attr('s', '45');
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: You do like override export button click event and check how many rows in data table if it is less then 1000 then you trigger export if not then show error message.

Comment: @PareshGami Thank you. 
 ```   action: function(e, dt, button, config) {
console.log('aa',dt); 
$.fn.DataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5.action(e, dt, button, config);
},  ```

can we get count of rows from passing arguments ?